# How to convert an enum value to a string?

Tags: string, delphi, enumeration

I know I have been able to do this before, long ago, so it must be possible.

I'd like to convert an item, such as a component's align property alNone, to a string that I can save, display, whatever. I know I can get the byte value and the come up with my own text, but I'm sure there is a more direct way.

For example I want to...

```
var S:string;
S:= somehow(Form.Align);
ShowMessage(S);
```

where "somehow" is however it is I convert the setting for the form's align property to a string such as "alNone'.

Comment: Or simply, in your case `S := TRttiEnumerationType.GetName<TAlign>(Form.Align)`

Comment: @Graymatter yes it is the same question, but there the answer is also wrong because the reinvent the wheel

Comment: @Graymatter he exactly my answer. Which someone doesn't like

Comment: @JensBorrisholt It depends on the version of Delphi. I think `TRttiEnumerationType` was only introduced in XE2 so the other options are valid depending on the version of Delphi.

Comment: Correct as long as it is Delphi 2009+  due to generics

Answer (score 29):

You can convert between enum types and String back and forth using RTTI :

```
uses
  RTTI;

procedure TForm40.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  sAlign: string;
  eAlign: TAlign;
begin
  //Enum to string      
  sAlign := TRttiEnumerationType.GetName(eAlign);
 
  //string to enum
  eAlign := TRttiEnumerationType.GetValue<TAlign>(sAlign);
end;
```

Comment: `sAlign := TRttiEnumerationType.GetName(Align);` What is Align? You mean GetName(eAlign)?

Comment: So, it will return something like "alLeft"? If true, then, considering that all Delphi enumerations start with two prefix characters, we could cut exactly two characters and (hopefully) obtain a human-friendly string.

Comment: @AlexPi `Align` is `TForm.Align`.

Comment: Correct, yes it is

Answer (score 19):

`Form.Align` is not a value of `TPersistent`. It's a value of `TAlign` which is an enumeration type.

You can convert an enumeration value to a string with this piece of code:

```
type TEnumConverter = class
public
  class function EnumToInt<T>(const EnumValue: T): Integer;
  class function EnumToString<T>(EnumValue: T): string;
end;

class function TEnumConverter.EnumToInt<T>(const EnumValue: T): Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  Move(EnumValue, Result, sizeOf(EnumValue));
end;

class function TEnumConverter.EnumToString<T>(EnumValue: T): string;
begin
  Result := GetEnumName(TypeInfo(T), EnumToInt(EnumValue));
end;
```

You need to add `System.TypInfo` to the uses.

Do this to get `Form.Align` as string:

```
S := TEnumConverter.EnumToString(Form.Align)
```

Comment: The natural follow-up question is going to be how to convert the string back to the enum value. You may as well include that in TEnumConverter, too.

Comment: This works only for D2009 and above. For D2007 and below you should call TypInfo.GetEnumName() with the appropiate typeinfo( TEnumtype ) )

Comment: That's what *this* code already does, @Ritsaert. Generics simply provide a convenient wrapper. The essence of the answer is to call `GetEnumName` in whatever manner your version of Delphi allows.

Comment: This could be done via RTTI. TEnumConverter is reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @JensBorrisholt:  Could be done with old-style RTTI, so equally well one might ask why re-invent a generic version with no upside?

Comment: @RobKennedy: Yes, I simply state the essentials from the code. The rest is window dressing, limiting your Delphi version. Naturally having a convenient wrapper is nice but is still is... a wrapper and the question should answer how the answer is created, not focus on the wrapper in question (just my $0.02)

Comment: I didn't invent the generics version. It is already there in the RTL